# Delete items from dynamodb based on date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am new to dynamodb, I am able to delete an item based on key.

Below is the code snippet:

```
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
key.put("hash", new AttributeValue().withS("hashEncodedStringValue"));

DeleteItemRequest deleteItemRequest = new DeleteItemRequest().withTableName("HashTable").withKey(key);
```

I need to delete items less than 7 days old from my table. And my table has a field called 'created_at' in this format "2017-10-25 14:54:52.278"

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamodb to delete it automatically after 7 days you can create TTL field and update the timestamp, dynamodb will automatically delete it.

**Reference:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html

**CRUD Operations with Java:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPICRUDExample.html

Hope it helps.